# Sending a result with EndDialog Win32API in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, winapi, webautomation

I am running some automation in a C# program (.Net 4.0).  There is an issue with a modal dialog where I want to click the message away and continue testing.  I have tried a few options (SendKey and using Win32 to send a click event with code modified from here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg309183.aspx.  Neither of these have proved to be reliable enough to be considered effective.

My next approach will be to try calling the EndDialog() function from my C# program and simply sending the enumeration/return code to the message box.

EndDialog(HWND hDlg, INT_PTR nResult) is the call where hDlg is the handle to the message box being closed and nResult is the result of the dialog.

Where I am running into an issue is how to send the desired result.  An example would be that the return code IDCANCEL has a value of 2.  How exactly do I send this value?  What variables or constants would I need to declare?  I'm just looking for how to get the proper pointer declared to send the desired result to the function.

Further information on these result values can be found here [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645505(v=VS.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645505%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

just invoke PostMessage. Here is a sample in c/c++:

::PostMessage(hWnd, WM_COMMAND, MAKEWPARAM(IDCANCEL,BN_CLICKED), 0);